# Can Python object be referenced under cdef function?

Tags: cython

In the code below, `self` is a python object, as it is declared from `def` instead of `cdef`. Can a python object be referenced under a `cdef` function, just like how it is used under the `c_function` from my example below?

I am confused because `cdef` makes it sound like `cdef` is a C function, so I am not sure if it is able to take on a python object.

```py
class A(self, int w):
   def __init__():
       self.a = w

   cdef c_function (self, int b):
       return self.a + b
```

Thank you,

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: ah perhaps I should try it myself, but all of this Cython stuff is new to me, I don't know how to run the Cython code just yet, I am just trying to write down all the Python code and translate them into Cython code first instead....I will try to run it....

Comment: I'd start by just taking your Python code and compiling it in Cython. Your Python code _should already be_ Cython code (mostly...) - it just may not be 100% optimzied Cython code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the OP.
From "Cython: A Guide for Python Programmers":

Source: https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=H3JmBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=python+object+cdef+function&source=bl&ots=QI9If_wiyR&sig=ACfU3U1CmEPBaEVmW0UN1_9m9G8B9a6oFQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBgs3Lw5vqAhXSZt4KHTs0DK0Q6AEwBHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=python%20object%20cdef%20function&f=false

```
"[...] Nothing prevents us from declaring and using Python objects and dynamic variables in cdef functions, or accepting them as arguments"
```

So I take this as the book saying "yes" to my original question.

Comment: This is correct. However, exact code you posted won't work because you can't have a `cdef` function as a member of a regular class (they can be global, or a member of a `cdef class`).